# How to get the columns names along with resultset for Perl/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, perl

I'm working with a Perl script that will connect to SQL server and get the data that I wanted. So I'm done with the Query that will show the result that I want, My problem is it only show the result set and not including the column names. I want to print also the column name along with the result set.

Here's my script

```
my $sql = "SELECT top (20) [code] AS Code
      ,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      ([name],'\“','\"'),'\”','\"'),'<= ','&le;'),'>=','&ge;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),CHAR(10),'<br>'),'\n',' '),CHAR(13),' '),'–','-'),'’',''+NCHAR(39)+'') AS ShortDesc
      ,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
      ([description],'\“','\"'),'\”','\"'),'<= ','&le;'),'>=','&ge;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),CHAR(10),'<br>'),'\n',' '),CHAR(13),' '),'–','-'),'’',''+NCHAR(39)+'') AS LongDesc
      ,CASE WHEN isobsolete = 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'Y' END AS Obsolete
      
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY effectivefromdate DESC) rn, * 
     FROM [CodingSuite_STG].[Codes].[Hcpcs] ) cs
     WHERE  rn=1 
     order by code asc";
     
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

 
#Execute the statement
$sth->execute();


while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
     print "@row\n";
}

#Close the connection
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

[just like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Sod.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation of [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI):

```
my @names = @{ $sth->{NAME} };
```

Comment: Also, [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) and derivatives.

Comment: Hi choroba, how can i use this function? its not working for me

Comment: @johndenverabella: Where did you put the command? What did it return?

Comment: Anywhere after the `prepare` call. Where did you put the command? What did it return?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref):

```
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print join(', ', map { "$_=$row->{$_}" } sort keys %$row);
}
```

Comment: hello it doesnt work for me , why is that, :(

Comment: it say DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_hashref failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (SQL-HY010) at HCPCS.pl line 46.

Comment: it produce an output on where all result set have an column name on it, i only want  to produce an output where it will show column name and under it the resultset, just like this

Comment: Those clarifications are the sort of thing that would be very useful in the original question.